# How to make a sprite display a variable

Tags: mit-scratch

I am making an Undertale-based game on Scratch, and I am trying to make a health counter that shows how much health you have. I could always make the health variable viewable but I want it to fit in with the game and not stick out like a sore thumb. I've seen other games such as Candy Clicker do this but I don't know how to replicate it. Does anybody know how to do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://scratch.mit.edu/discuss/topic/172652/

Comment: No im not trying to hide/show them, im trying to make it so that a sprite will display the number of the variable on it without having the variable box visible to make it look nicer

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. To customize the appearance of score on screen, use digit costumes. See griffpatch's "Awesome Number Counters" tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=atMwy3UKc14

Comment: Alright ill be sure to look at it, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do a sprite counter similar to Candy Clicker, you would need to use clones. You need to create a sprite with costumes for 0-9 numbers. Then you would need to have that sprite clone itself for however many digits you want to display, let's say 3, and then set its costume to the letter number of the variable that the clone's digit corresponds to. I'm not great at explaining stuff like this, so that might have seemed a bit complicated, so the short version is you need to create sprites that display the digits from costumes. I have created a demo at https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/677633446/editor with comments in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Just put the variable in a "Say Block" and put that in a "Forever Loop".

Comment: I am aware you can do that but that's not exactly what im looking for.
Im looking for something similar to Candy Clicker's counter.